# Check isset variable _GET and check if existe in database

Tags: mysql, variables, get

How can i check if variable _GET isset and compare if that variable value exist in database?

I have this follow code:

```
//require connection bd

$vtld = $_GET['tld']; //variable from _GET

$sql="SELECT extension FROM tbldomainpricing";

$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

if ($row['extension'] == '$vtld') {
    echo $vtld.' variavel exist' ;
} else {
    echo $vtld.' variavel not exist';
}
```

The page A send variable _GET and page B recive that variable and check if exist in database

Page A - EX: domain.com/folder/index.php?page=tld&**tld=.org**

Page B - recive variable and check if exist.

thanks in advance

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove quotes for the '$vtld'.some thing like this may work

```
if(isset($_GET['tld'])) {
    $vtld = $_GET['tld']; //variable from _GET

    $sql="SELECT extension FROM tbldomainpricing";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    if ($row['extension'] == $vtld) {
        echo $vtld.' variavel exist' ;
    } else {
        echo $vtld.' variavel not exist';
    }
}
```